# Vscode keybinding to jump to the start of the line of code ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, ubuntu-22.04

I am using Vscode 1.72.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.1.

I am looking for the keybinding to jump to the start of the current lines code, not the very start of the line, but the start of the line of code.

For example i am currently using the keyboard binding:

```
 {
    "key": "alt+left",
    "command": "cursorLineStart"
}
```

which results in the cursor being here:

[cursor example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lEhC.png)

where i want the cursor to jump to right before c of 'class'.

Comment: have you tried `Home`, maybe 2 times

Comment: @rioV8 thank you this worked, the keybinding command is called "cursorHome"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @rioV8 comment i found the keybinding command which is:

```
"command": "cursorHome"
```